# Are metric tensors (or even pseudo-metric tensors) really metrics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, terminology

In some discussions of [metric tensors $g : TM_p \times TM_p \rightarrow \mathbb R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) (and even of pseudo-metric tensors, for instance in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299431)), and of the corresponding [first fundamental forms ${\rm d}s^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Arclength_and_the_line_element),
these (mathematical) objects are referred to as "metric".

Is this serious and correct terminology?

Is it really true that metric tensors, or (even) pseudo-metric tensors, and/or the corresponding first fundamental forms are [metrics (in the specific well-known sense)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition),
by which accordingly $g : X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ for some suitable set $X$, such that $\forall x, y, z \in X$:

- [$g[~x, y~] \neq 0 ~ ~\Leftrightarrow ~ ~ x \not\equiv y ~$ (distinguishability of distinct elements)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinction),
- [$g[~x, y~] = g[~y, x~]$ (symmetry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function),
- [$g[~x, z~] \le g[~x, y~] + g[~y, z~]$ (subadditivity; triangle inequality)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality)

?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: "_1. How is this a physics question?_" -- It came up due to [this physics answer (already linked in the OP)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/299431). "_2. The Riemannian case is answered by the paragraph Riemannian manifolds as metric spaces of the corresponding Wikipedia article._" -- The article defines the metric $$d[~x,y~] = \text{inf}[~\int_x^y dt~\|\gamma'[~t~]\|~],$$ but it doesn't claim that the metric tensor $g$ **is this** metric. Therefore, if $g$ **is** strictly supposed to be a metric, then which one, explicitly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, but note that the metric tensor $g$ *defines* the distance function on $TM$ and hence a norm, it is not itself the distance function.

In particular, for $TM$ we can define

$$d(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) \equiv \sqrt{g(\vec{x} - \vec{y}, \vec{x} - \vec{y})}
  \quad\forall \vec{x}, \vec{y} \in TM$$

It's relatively easy to show that if $g$ is a metric (as opposed to a pseudometric) this definition of $d$ works as you would expect.

Note that I am answering about the relationship between $g$ and $d$ on $TM$: $g$ also makes $M$ a metric space, but that's a slightly different argumentt.

Comment: tfb: "_Yes, it is true, [...] the metric tensor $g$ [...] is not itself the distance function._" -- That's the acceptable answer; where "metric" is the standard synonym for "_distance function_". "_In particular, for TM we can define_ $d$ _[...]_" -- Is the triangle ineq. thereby satisfied? (Take $\vec y := 2~\vec x, \vec z := 3~\vec x$, all $\in TM$.) "$g$ _also makes $M$ a metric space [...]_" -- You're doing well to draw the distinction, and I find this (or vice versa, how a metric space might induce a metric tensor) far more interesting; but that's indeed beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @user12262 I will elaborate the answer with the triangle inequality, but later when I have a computer...

Answer (score 1):

From the metric we get a curve length, if the manifold is connected we can define a distance function as the infimum of curve lengths between two points (this exists if the metric is positive definite). It is easily checked that this defines a metric in the usual sense.

A Lorentzian metric does not define a metric in the usual sense, as points may be connected by a zero length curve.

Comment: doetoe: "_From the metric we get a curve length [...]_" -- Sure:
[$$\text{length} (\gamma)=\sup \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n d(\gamma(t_i),\gamma(t_{i-1})) : n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } a = t_0 < t_1 < \dotsb < t_n = b \right\}.$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Length_of_a_curve) But perhaps you mean that from the metric **tensor** we'd get a curve length ??

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact this is totally standard terminology, however since that was part of your confusion I should maybe have been more explicit.

Comment: doetoe: "_In fact this_ [... calling some object "metric" which is not strictly a metric ...] _is totally standard terminology_" -- Not by the standard of using terminology consistent with its (usual, explicit) definition (if there is one). But perhaps you only meant that the abuse of terminology is (presently) widespread? ...

Answer (score 0):

It works if the metric has only positive eigenvalues. It is not the case, for example, for Minkowski space where $g(V,V)=0$ for some vectors (light-like ones).

Comment: Andrew Feldman: "_It works if the metric has only positive eigenvalues._" -- How could this satisfy [$g[~x, y~] \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow x \not\equiv y$ (distinguishability of distinct elements)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distinction) ?

Comment: @user12262 It does not (only the rightward implication holds), but in a very common abuse of terminology we refer to this as a metric anyway. In reality such a quadratic form gives what is known as a *pseudo-Riemannian structure* on the manifold. In particular, when the signature of the metric is $(1,3)$ we have what are called *Lorentzian manifolds*, the natural setting of the theory of general relativity.